# Approximate a curve given n 2d points and calculate angle/derivate at those n locations

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, calculus

I am looking to calculate a curve that contains n x,y points such as x=[0,2,3,5,8] and y=[8,3,-1,0,-2]. I am looking to use n-1 degree polynom. Then I would like to compute the angle/first derivative at each of the x locations.

So far I have tried a mix of numpy.polifit and scipy curve fitting without much success. I have also checked splines but not so interested in further splitting the interval as I know the points where I will be wanting to calculate the angle already.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"So far I have tried a mix of numpy.polifit and scipy curve fitting without much success."* Show what you have tried--and what went wrong--in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of points and the degree you're looking for match, you can find the unique solution using Lagrange interpolation.

- [Wikipedia on Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation);
- [`scipy.interpolate.lagrange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html).

```py
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange

X=[0,2,3,5,8]
Y=[8,3,-1,0,-2]

P = lagrange(X,Y)
P_deriv = P.deriv()
derivatives = [P_deriv(x) for x in X]

print(P)
print(P_deriv)
print(derivatives)

#           4         3         2
# -0.08611 x + 1.261 x - 5.169 x + 3.483 x + 8
#
#          3         2
# -0.3444 x + 3.783 x - 10.34 x + 3.483
#
# [3.483, -4.817, -2.783, 3.317, -13.45]
```

If you want to get the tangential angles rather than the derivatives, you can call `numpy.arctan` on the array `derivatives`.

Comment: Hi Stef, thank you so much for your code, it does exactly what I was after. Interesting to use the Langrange approach, just what I needed. One thing to note though is that I don't think the actual equation that got printed is the real one. As it is 5 points, it should be an x^4...which is what I actually get when I run the code. Might be worth double checking for others to use as guidance. Thanks again!

Comment: @HectorArroyoGzlez Oops, you're right. Fixed.